# Is using a .txt file as database of meta tags secure?

Tags: php, mysql, security, meta-tags

I came across a [snippet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219015508/http://hawkee.com/snippet/3640) that uses the *meta_tags.txt* as a database of meta tags for its website's pages. I was planning to implement it in one of my projects. I am also planning in using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for the variables before "printing".

Being a security freak, is this method secure? or do I have to add additional security measures to prevent other malicious attacks? Maybe, a MySQL table instead of a text document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only risk I see in using this method is to make sure that you protect that file through Apache's `.htaccess` if you wish to protect sensitive information, should that file contain any later on or that you want to build a database for other things such as a user base, newsletters, etc.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

For example:

```
<files "file.txt">
deny from all 
</files>
```

and placed outside the webroot of your server.

However, using a text file as a database is a lot of work though when it comes to modifying it such as updating, deleting, searching, etc., so you may want to think about your options.

One of which is using a database along with prepared statements is also a good bet and is a lot more manageable.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Flat file database references:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database
- http://www.sqlite.org/ (works well with PHP http://php.net/sqlite)

JSON is also another option:

- http://www.json.org/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: To save me from headaches later, I'll just use a MySQL table instead of text file.

Answer (score 0):

htaccess with `.` (dot) before file name are Your friends.

At least on Apache/Linux environment.

Simply add a single dot before current name to each .txt file, and by doing that You will make that file system/hidden.

Instead of `/my/dir/outside/root/mymetadb.txt` - `/my/dir/outside/root/.mymetadb.txt`

Than add this to your main .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

`RewriteBase /` might be unnecessary.

After this, be it directory or a file, each and every one, starting with a single dot, will be forbidden/unreachable by end-users.

This is ideal if You only have server webroot access, and do want textual db files.

Considering custom db files, think about .php files instead of plain .txt. 
You can read custom `.mydb.php` files via `file_get_contents`, `require` ... and normally, `var_export($contents)` into, when needed. :)

Comment: I will keep this in my mind and try to tinker with this idea.